# Coarrays disabled use -fcoarrays=?

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, fortran-coarrays

I'm trying to run a Fortran code that follows the example for the book:

```
Curcic, M. 2020. Modern Fortran: Building Efficient Parallel Applications.
```

Although I get the following error when I run it and I'm not experienced enough to understand what the problem is, could someone kindly help me?

```
program hello
    implicit none

    integer :: a[*]  ! error here
    integer :: i

    a = this_image()

    if (this_image() == 1) then
        do i = 1, num_images()
            print *, 'Value on image', i, 'is', a[i]
        end do
    end if

end program
```

> Error: Coarrays disabled at (1), use '-fcoarray=' to enable|

Comment: You are trying to use coarrays in your program but your compiler does not enable such things by default and should add an option like `-fcoarray=single`. This is quite a broad topic (going as far as needing to install extra libraries) so can you explain why you are trying this program? (Coarrays are an advanced Fortran topic, we can't answer well without knowing your background.)

Comment: @francescalus I'm new to FORTRAN and have experiences with Java, R and Python although I have aspiration towards working with meteorological data and have been told FORTRAN is the goto language for this, therefore I've just recently started learning the language with intentions over the next 2 months to manipulate and analyze very large dataset in preparation for meteorological data, and higher-order function. I'm entirely self-taught and have received all my education from reading books and help from the experienced community of stackoverflow

Comment: You will almost surely NOT need coarrays for needs. Those are needed for some modern parallel computing techniques. Meteorological prediction models normally use MPI instead, coarrays are too new for them. If you just want to analyze data on a single workstation you very likely won't even need MPI.

Comment: If your M. Curcic's book is mostly concerned about coarrays, you might have picked a wrong book for you. That is really mostly for people starting their own parallel project from scratch or joining a team that specifically works with coarrays. Instead, I would recommend some introductory book about Fotran, first without any special regard to parallel computing. There are many and different ones suit different readers.

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you for the tip! I believe the example was an introduction to what I will be expecting to know several chapters in. Given what you have mentioned about this, I am very excited to progress and learn, and hope to upload more questions as I continue to read.

Comment: You need to use OpenCoarrays compiler wrapper instead of gfortran. It is extremely easy to install, compile and use it: https://github.com/sourceryinstitute/OpenCoarrays

Comment: OpenCoarrays also has an online Jupyter binding for it that you could use for simple parallel Fortran code testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program use a special feature of standard Fortran called coarrays. They are used for modern parallel computing. However most traditional parallel programs used in computational physics and meteorology use MPI for distributed parallelism instead.

There is nothing wrong in learning coarrays at any stage, but it might not be the skill you are supposed to learn now. It is currently not the most useful skill for data analysis in meteorology.

With coarrays, different copies ("images") of the program are running concurrently on different CPU cores of a computer or even of several computing nodes in a cluster.

```
integer :: a[*]
```

means that the variable `a` exists  on each image and the images can look at the value in different images and read it or change it.

```
a[i]
```

means that you want to use the value of `a` at image number `i`.

To use Coarrays with Gfortran you either can compile the program as a (pretty-useless) single image program using `-fcoarray=single` or you have to install a dedicated library called [OpenCoarrays](http://www.opencoarrays.org/) and then compile with `-fcoarray=lib` pointing to the library.

Comment: For gfortran and -fcoarray=lib you may need to compile and  link with mpif90 and link against an appropriate library, which is -lcaf_openmpi on my linux box but I don't have enough experience here to comment more generally. This also means you will need mpi installed.